# WebService Call from Android 10

Tags: android

I'm able to consume my http web service call from all other android devices except samsung Galaxy A70(Android 10). There are 10 web-service call we are consuming one after one.

Added `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` tag also in Application manifest file.

The error we are getting is:- IOException: Connection to http://www.blablabla.com refused.

Is anyone face the similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

you also need to add below code inbeetween your  tag like this

```
 <uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false" />
```

If still you have issue; then

add this below line of code inside your `application` tag

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

create one xml file inside your `res > xml` folder, name it like `"network_security_config.xml"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
        <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
            <domain includeSubdomains="true">http://www.blablabla.com</domain>
        </domain-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="TRUE" />
</network-security-config>
```

change your website root here.